# How do I see the primary key of a table? And how can I add multiple primary keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, pgadmin-4

I have the following table: https://i.imgur.com/gWyCQxS.png

```
db name: testdb
table name: testtable
```

I purposely did not create any primary keys when creating the table because I wanted to learn how to it afterwards.

I used the following to add a primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE testtable
ADD PRIMARY KEY (column2);
```

In pgAdmin, I can see that it worked: https://i.imgur.com/3wKsOLo.png

I tried to do the same for `column1` but I got this error: `ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "testtable" are not allowed SQL state: 42P16`

**Q1: Why am I not allowed to have multiple primary keys for this table and how can I add multiple ones?**

Also, **without using the pgAdmin GUI**, I'm trying to see what the current primary key is for `testtable`. I found a thread here on Stackoverflow that recommended the following code:

```
select OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint
FROM sys.objects
where OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)='testtable'
and type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
```

I get an error after executing this: `ERROR:  relation "sys.objects" does not exist`.

**Q2: How can I view all of the primary keys using psql or without using the pgAdmin GUI?**

Comment: 1) It is impossible to have several PKs, only one PK possibly on multiple columns 2) Look at the [`pg_constraint` catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html) where `contype = 'p'` With the `psql` use `\d <tablename>` metacommand

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) the `psql` command to view the table definition including the primary key is `\d`

Comment: Using AziMez's method below, I was able to add two primary keys: https://i.imgur.com/heBzuhP.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A1:** Try to use a composite KEY like this:

```
ALTER TABLE testtable
ADD PRIMARY KEY (column1,column2);
```

**A2:** (Q2: How can I view all of the primary keys using psql?)

Something like this:

```
select tc.table_schema, tc.table_name, kc.column_name
from information_schema.table_constraints tc
  join information_schema.key_column_usage kc 
    on kc.table_name = tc.table_name and kc.table_schema = tc.table_schema and kc.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
where tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
  and kc.ordinal_position is not null
order by tc.table_schema,
         tc.table_name,
         kc.position_in_unique_constraint;
```

Comment: What does A2 look like for poster’s table

Comment: Marichyasana- EDIT A2: is Answer for Q2: How can I view all of the primary keys using psql or without using the pgAdmin GUI?

Comment: I get the following: https://i.imgur.com/uvF6WhY.png which does seem to show me the primary key. Thank you!

Comment: I tried `ALTER TABLE testtable ADD PRIMARY KEY (column1,column2);` but it gives me the same error.

Comment: You must remove any old PRIMARY KEY, before redefine it. in your case you must firstly remove the KEY(column2)

Comment: ALTER TABLE testtable  DROP CONSTRAINT column2;

Comment: I tried using the command exactly as above but it resulted in a syntax error. I think the name of the constraint needs to be used after `CONSTRAINT`. I used a_horse_with_no_name method of `\d testtable` to find the name of the constraint and `ALTER TABLE testtable DROP CONSTRAINT testtable_pkey` to drop the constraint. This worked: https://i.imgur.com/heBzuhP.png

Comment: Do you know how I can edit the constraint rather than delete it and then add a second one? For example, I used your command to set both `column1` and `column2` as the primary keys but suppose I wanted to remove just one of the columns.